# xdmp:log Error while using CPF (MarkLogic)

Tags: alert, marklogic

I attempted to follow a tutorial on Marklogic for creating our own CPF. I pretty much copy and pasted all the codes and most of the functionalities worked aside from xdmp:log. The CPF would end it's task upon reaching it. The documentation from marklogic can be found here [Getting Started with a Simple CPF Application](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/quickStart)

In case I did something wrong I will post my codes here and what I did.

=======Documents Used=======

add-last-updated.xqy => added into Modules DB

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf" 
  at "/MarkLogic/cpf/cpf.xqy";
declare variable $cpf:document-uri as xs:string external;
declare variable $cpf:transition as node() external;
if (cpf:check-transition($cpf:document-uri,$cpf:transition)) then try {
  let $doc := fn:doc($cpf:document-uri)
  return
      xdmp:node-insert-child(
        $doc/book,
        <last-updated>{fn:current-dateTime()}</last-updated>
      ),
  xdmp:log( "add last-updated ran OK" ),
  cpf:success($cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, ())
} catch ($e) {
  cpf:failure($cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, $e, ())
}
else ()
```

add-copyright.xqy => added into Modules DB

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace cpf = "http://marklogic.com/cpf" 
  at "/MarkLogic/cpf/cpf.xqy";
declare variable $cpf:document-uri as xs:string external;
declare variable $cpf:transition as node() external;
if (cpf:check-transition($cpf:document-uri,$cpf:transition)) then try {
  let $doc := fn:doc( $cpf:document-uri )
  return
      xdmp:node-insert-child( 
        $doc/book,
        <copyright>
          <year>2010</year>
          <holder>The Publisher</holder>
        </copyright>),
      xdmp:log( "add copyright ran OK" ),
      cpf:success( $cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, () )
}
catch ($e) {
  cpf:failure( $cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, $e, () )
}
else ()
```

copyright.xml => added into Pipeline and attached to "Default Documents" Domain

```
<pipeline xmlns="http://marklogic.com/cpf/pipelines">
  <pipeline-name>Copyright Pipeline</pipeline-name>
  <pipeline-description>Pipeline to test CPF</pipeline-description>
  <success-action>
    <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/success-action.xqy</module>
  </success-action>
  <failure-action>
    <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/failure-action.xqy</module>
  </failure-action>
  <state-transition>
    <annotation>
      When a document containing ‘book' as a root element is created, 
      add a ‘copyright' statement.
    </annotation>
    <state>http://marklogic.com/states/initial</state>
    <on-success>http://marklogic.com/states/done</on-success>
    <on-failure>http://marklogic.com/states/error</on-failure>
    <execute>
      <condition>
        <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
        <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
          <root-element>book</root-element>
          <namespace/>
        </options>
      </condition>
      <action>
        <module>add-copyright.xqy</module>
      </action>
    </execute>
  </state-transition>
  <state-transition>
    <annotation>
      When a document containing ‘book' as a root element is updated, 
      add a ‘last-updated' element
    </annotation>
    <state>http://marklogic.com/states/updated</state>
    <on-success>http://marklogic.com/states/done</on-success>
    <on-failure>http://marklogic.com/states/error</on-failure>
    <execute>
      <condition>
        <module>/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy</module>
        <options xmlns="/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/namespace-condition.xqy">
          <root-element>book</root-element>
          <namespace/>
        </options>
      </condition>
      <action>
        <module>add-last-updated.xqy</module>
      </action>
    </execute>
  </state-transition>
</pipeline>
```

======Tested Using======

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $contents :=   
  <book>
    <bookTitle>All About George</bookTitle>
    <chapter1>
      <chapterTitle>Curious George</chapterTitle>
      <para>
        George Washington crossed the Delaware to see what was on the other side.
      </para>
    </chapter1>
  </book>
return
  xdmp:document-insert("/content.xml", $contents)
```

In general the code works and the Document is edited outputting upon the first insertion as shown below, but the logs found in MarkLogic/Data/Logs/8000_ErrorLog were not updated. Additionally, when I attempted to bring xdmp:log above xdmp:node-insert-child the CPF stops prematurely and the node does not get edited. I would greatly appreciate any advise to help with this issue.

```
<book>
  <bookTitle>All About George</bookTitle>
  <chapter1>
    <chapterTitle>Curious George</chapterTitle>
    <para>
      George Washington crossed the Delaware to see what was on the other side.
    </para>
  </chapter1>
  <copyright>
    <year>2010</year>
    <holder>The Publisher</holder>
  </copyright>
</book>
```

========Update========

I followed mholstege recommendation and removed my "return" and "let" statement as well as trailing the logs as grtjn suggested. From there I realized the logs was being pushed into "TaskServer_Error" logs. A silly issue on my part and thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I think you need to look in a different ErrorLog, probably the TaskServer_ErrorLog.txt. I typically do something like `tail -f *_ErrorLog.txt` to follow all error logs in one go..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have formatted the code suggest to me you think the `xdmp:log` and `cpf:success` lines fall under the `return`, but that is not the case: only the first expression after the `return` is. So you are probably getting an undefined variable static error on this module when you reorder the lines. You don't really need the `let` and `return`: you could just put use `doc($document-uri)/book` directly in the `xdmp:node-replace` call. Then you could reorder the sequence at will. If you want the `xdmp:node-replace` and the `xdmp:log` to be in the scope of the `$doc` variable, wrap parentheses around that sequence of expressions.